# Passing $PSScriptRoot while using -startjob

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, jobs

I made a PowerShell gui app which can launch second window with tools etc. It works but I didnt wanted first window to be frozen while second is running so I used start-job. Now I can't find a way to pass $PSScriptRoot from parent to newly created window. I'm using a function to create whole gui and code is:

`Start-Job -ScriptBlock ${Function:Create-Gui2}`

Tried putting param with -argumentlist but doesn't work for some reason. Appreciate any help

Comment: I made a workaround getting drive letter and path by drive label as it's run from pendrive. Isn't pretty but do the work. Still would love to see how it should be made